# Why Fullcalendar getDate method returns time in GMT+0000 timezone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

My timezone is GMT+0200 and my actual hour in my timezone is 13:02. Although in Fullcalendar running this code:

```
$('#owner-calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').toString();
```

I receive that:

```
"Fri Sep 22 2017 13:02:19 GMT+0000"
```

Why is my timezone ignored? Is it proper behavior?

Comment: Have you set your timezone? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/

Comment: Oh, I didn't have it set, thanks! (BTW, that's quite counterintuitive that 'local' timezone isn't default).